# Processing a buttonclick in Oracle forms programticly for an implementation class

Tags: java, oracleforms

I am having the following problem which is exclusive to the oracle forms framework and custom implementation classes provided in java. I modified a `VButton` to display a custom menue as soon as i am pressing the right mouse button.

The following was accomplished by inheriting from the `VButton` and providing a custom behavior.

The popup will be displayed by a `JPopupMenu`. This `JPopupMenu` will be filled dynamicly by a `HashMap<String, JMenuItem>` which represents each option in this JPopupMenu and it´s representing key. To accomplish this i wrote an abstract class which contains everything that needs to be done to create a custom right click menu, with two abstract methods. These methods will be overriden by subclasses of this class and will create two representing lists of Keys for the `Map` and theyr representing `JMenuItem`.

This is how the abstract class is designed.

```
public abstract class AbstractRightClickButton extends VButton{
    // The PopupMenu for this item;
    private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    // The HashMap that stores the Menuitems and it´s keys
    private HashMap<String, JMenuItem> menuItems = new HashMap<String, JMenuItem>();
    // Stores the current selected key.
    private String choice= "";

    public AbstractRightClickButton() {
        this.menuItems = generateHashmap();
        initMouseListener();
        initPopUp();
    }

    // Abstract method to create an ArrayList of all JMenuItem
    public abstract ArrayList<JMenuItem> generateJMenuItemSide();
    // Abstract method to create an ArrayList for each key in the HashMap
    public abstract ArrayList<String> generateStringSide();

    private void initPopUp() {
        ArrayList<String> list = generateStringSide();
        for (String counter : list) {
            popup.add(menuItems.get(counter));
        }
    }

    private void initMouseListener() {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    // If the width of the popup is 0 then it wasn´t displayed yet. Just show it once and make it invisible again to get the width and height of the popup.
                    if (popup.getWidth() == 0)  { 
                        popup.show(AbstractRightClickButton.this, AbstractRightClickButton.this.getWidth(), 0);
                        popup.setVisible(false);
                    }
                    popup.show(AbstractRightClickButton.this, AbstractRightClickButton.this.getWidth()-popup.getWidth(), 0);
                }
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        });

    protected HashMap<String, JMenuItem> generateHashmap() {
        HashMap<String, JMenuItem> map = new HashMap<String, JMenuItem>();
        ArrayList<String> key = generateStringSide();
        ArrayList<JMenuItem> value = generateJMenuItemSide();
        for (int i = 0;i < key.size();++i) {
            map.put(key.get(i), value.get(i));
        }
        return map;
    };

    // This method is a helper method that can be called by subclasses of AbstractRightClickButton
    // It creates a JMenutButton based on the parameter
    protected JMenuItem generateJMenuItem(final String key, final boolean click) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction(key) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                choice = key; 
                if (click) {
                    ActionEvent act  = new ActionEvent((Object)AbstractRightClickButton.this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, ""); // Button Event erstellen
                    AbstractRightClickButton.this.processEvent(act); // Event Processen um den Buttondruck Formsseitig auch auszulösen
                }
            }
        });
        return item;
    }
}
```

A concrete class would look like this

```
public class ConcreteRightClickButton extends AbstractRightClickButton{
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> generateStringSide() {
        ArrayList<String> basis = new ArrayList<String>(0);

        basis.add("OPTION1");
        basis.add("OPTION2");

        return basis;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<JMenuItem> generateJMenuItemSide() {
        ArrayList<JMenuItem> basis = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>(0);

        basis.add(generateJMenuItem("OPTION1", true));
        basis.add(generateJMenuItem("OPTION2", true));

        return basis;
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing depends on the type of button, espacially how this button is defined in the forms builder. If the button property `iconic` is defined as `No`, then the call of `AbstractRightClickButton.this.processEvent(act)` correctly processes this event and can be handelt by the `When-Button-Pressed` Event in Oracle Forms. But if the button property `iconic` is defined as `Yes` then the processing of the event somehow doesn´t work. While Debugging everything looks fine, there is no exception and it reaches the `AbstractRightClickButton.this.processEvent(act)` without any problem. But the representing `When-Button-Pressed` Trigger in Oracle Forms doesn´t react. Am i processing the Event incorrectly or is there something else that stops oracle forms from recieving this event?

I am using `Oracle forms 11g` to create a mask containing this specific button.

Answer (score 0):

1 year 8 months later, maybe this isn't an "answer" but its an alternative way to do the same thing.
Create a class that extends VBean, and create a JButton.

Add the jar to the classpath, and call it within a Bean Area.

It's called java pluggable components.

This page is useful:
[JPC](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com)

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import oracle.forms.ui.VBean;

public class TryButton extends VBean {

    JButton button = new JButton();

    public TryButton() {

        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
        button.setSize(500, 500);
        button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/imagen2.png")));
    }

}
```

Then, add the jar to: oracle_home/forms/java
and add it to classpath

In oracle forms in a new canvas create a Bean Area
Go to Item Properties and add the class package and name to: implementation class.

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) example of how to apply your suggestion, and add relevant quotes from the linked resource(s).